# Intellisense for TypeScript module used in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I use the Node AWS SDK in my JavaScript files (modules), Intellisense shows me the types of the arguments for function calls.

When I code up my own module in TypeScript and try to use one of its exports in VS Code, the types of function arguments are always shown as `any`, even though I may have a type of `string[]` or `string` in the `.ts` file. For example:

[image: Intellisense for sendTemplatedEmail]

Even though the code is:

```
export function sendTemplatedEmail(toAddrArr: string[], templateName: string, data: {}, from: string,
    ccAddrArr: string[], bccAddrArr: string[]) {
    const dest = recipients2Destination(toAddrArr, ccAddrArr, bccAddrArr);
    return sendEmailPromise(dest, from, templateName, data);
}
```

Of course, I am compiling the `.ts` file to a `.js` file and then requiring the `.js` file in my Javascript code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you generating a index.d.ts in your typescript library that has all the types?

Comment: No. How do I generate this file & where do I place it @AlexanderStaroselsky? Plus, what I have written so far is a single `.ts` file with a 2-3 exports in it.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

Comment: Also generate from compiler options `—declaration` flag: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html